# Stucco around lumber

Tags: lumber, stucco

I have a masonry wall that I'd like to hang a 2x6 on (6 side against the wall) so that I can use it as an anchor for a curtain rod. I would then like to stucco around it. I was wondering if it's okay for stucco to be in direct contact with lumber. The lumber will be prominent even after the stucco is applied as I don't plan to make them flush, so aesthetics is not an issue.

Comment: A few more details would be good to know. Is the masonry wall part of a living space, so that the applied stucco is part of the weathering package of the wall/building? Is the 2X6 pressure treated?

Answer (score 1):

It is fine for stucco to be in contact with the lumber.  But if you are stuccoing over the lumber, you will need to protect it with a wrap and then the wire mesh for the stucco to hold on to.

Comment: Not stuccoing over

Answer (score 0):

For a clean and neat appearance you might want to consider installing a "J" channel along the 2 x 6's bottom edge. This is a length of metal roughly shaped like the letter J in profile. This is used for a three layered stucco system. It covers the stucco's edges for a clean and straight appearance. Sold in 10 foot sections. It would also compensate for any movement between the two dissimilar materials (wood and cement) and prevent cracking.